# Sending mail with PHP not working

Tags: php

My script to send an email via PHP is not working and I don't know why as there is no specific error. Please advise:

test@test.com is replaced with my real email address.

```
udrew_email("test@test.com", $_REQUEST["txtEmail"], "Gears Message", $_REQUEST["txtName"], $_REQUEST["txtMessage"]);

<?php
function udrew_email($strTo, $strFromEmail, $strSubject, $strFromName, $strBody)
{
$strHeaders = "From: " . $strFromName . "<" . $strFromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";
if (mail($strTo, $strSubject, $strBody, $strHeaders)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed.</p>");
}
}
?>
```

I get "Message delivery failed."

I've also tried placing constants in all the variables instead of requesting from my form.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured the server to send email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mail() returns false if it was unable to handle the email over to an smtp server. On unix, that'd be the local sendmail/postfix/exim. On Windows, it's whatever smtp server is configured in php.ini `SMTP` and `smtp_port` options.

That can be because the smtp server isn't running or is mis-configured. It can also be because the email is so badly formed the server rejects it outright without even TRYING to deliver it onwards.

Comment: This was definitely a problem. I have since configured it and still get the same error though. What would be the next step to troubleshoot?

Comment: Check the mail sever logs to see why the message is being rejected/bounced?

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that your mail server is running, and that you have one installed and set up. If it is then check the log files for your mail server.